# How to add auth endpoints to existing Sails V1 project?

Tags: sails.js

I have an existing Sails V1 project that was generated as an empty app (it uses a React front-end). I'd now like to add in the auth endpoints that would have been created if the app had been generated as a web app. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You need to hook up the policies and related actions. Your best bet, I would say, is to generate a new project, with the front-end included, and see how that is set up. It utilizes the policy-middleware to call the policy-actions.

```js
module.exports.policies = {

  '*': 'is-logged-in',

  // Bypass the `is-logged-in` policy for:
  'entrance/*': true,
  'account/logout': true,
  'view-homepage-or-redirect': true,
  'deliver-contact-form-message': true,
};
```

Here you see that the `policy.js` in the `/config` folder, calls `is-logged-in` for all controllers by default. You also see that there is some exceptions added below.

`is-logged-in` is the file `/api/policies/is-logged-in.js`:

```js
module.exports = async function (req, res, proceed) {
  // If `req.me` is set, then we know that this request originated
  // from a logged-in user.
  if (req.me) {
    return proceed();
  }

  // Otherwise, this request did not come from a logged-in user.
  return res.unauthorized();
};
```

This is the part that does the check for the logged-in status of the user. You can see that it uses the `req.me` part, which is set up in the `api/hooks/custom/index.js`. Here it loads the user from the database and makes the logged in users data available on the req object.

If you don't have, or want to use, this hook, you can exchange `req.me` with `req.session.userId`, assuming that you set the `userId` on the session-object on your login-handler. Example from Sails-code:

```
....
var userRecord = await User.findOne({
  emailAddress: inputs.emailAddress.toLowerCase(),
});

// check user exist
....

// check password
....

//check remember-me 
....

// Modify the active session instance.
this.req.session.userId = userRecord.id;

// Send success response (this is where the session actually gets persisted)
return exits.success();
....
```

I hope this gets you on the right path, at least in terms of where to dig deeper.